# Dirichlet problem in terms of a Fourier sine series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, dirichlet-series

Solve the Dirichlet problem

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{t} - 2u - u_{xx} =0 & \quad \mbox{$0<x<1,t>0$}, \\
\quad u(x,0) =  \begin{cases} x & \textrm{ if $0\le x\le 1/2$} \\ 1-x & \textrm{ if $1/2\le x\le 1$} \end{cases}, \\
\quad u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0. 
\end{array} 
\right. $$

expressing the solution in terms of a Fourier sine series.

Also if anyone could help me solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a straight forward application of separation of variables. What have you tried?

Comment: @Mattos I am not sure how to go about solving it in the first place

Comment: Then you need to read up on [separation of variables for PDEs](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeparationofVariables.aspx).

Comment: @Mattos Would this problem be similar to example 6 on the site you attached?

Comment: Yes, somewhat. Though they don't explain on the attached site how to then solve the ODEs, use superposition, apply the initial conditions or compute the coefficients using orthogonality. So you are going to have to do some reading.

Comment: @Mattos I have substituted $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ into the equation and got $XT' + 2XT - X''T$. Then by algebra I isolated $X''/X$ and got $X''/X = (T'+2T)/T = - \lambda$. Which leads to the eigenvalue problem $X'' + \lambda X = 0$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: It should be $XT' - 2XT - X''T = 0 \implies X''/X = (T' - 2T)/T = -\lambda$. But yes, your approach is correct. Now You need to solve the ODE $X'' = -\lambda X$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t) = X(0)T(t) = 0 \implies X(0) = 0$. Similarly, we also get $u(1,t) = X(1)T(t) = 0 \implies X(1) = 0$. You'll need to check the different cases $\lambda < 0, \lambda = 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ to find the non-trivial eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.